# escape newlines in a string because of maximum line length

Tags: r

Is there a way to escape a newline in a string? I try to break my lines of code at about 80 characters, but sometimes I write messages which are longer than those lines. Is there a way to just escape the newline? I don't want to paste multiple strings into a single one.

```
cat(sprintf(
  '%s Re-quantify was set to "True"! Please reanalyse data with correct settings and start the script again.\n',
  date()))
```

And if I add new lines, the message is also printed in two lines

```
cat(sprintf(
  '%s Re-quantify was set to "True"! Please reanalyse data 
with correct settings and start the script again.\n',
  date()))
```

I am aware that `paste` solves my problem, but the code is harder to read I think.

```
cat(sprintf(
  paste('%s Re-quantify was set to "True"! Please reanalyse data', 
        'with correct settings and start the script again.\n'),
  date()))
```

So is there something I can do inline? Just using `\` to escape the newline didn't work.

Comment: Backslash should work to wrap text around.

Comment: @Gopala If i add a `backslash`   after `data` in my second example, I still get a two line printout.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it works. You could start the new line with a backspace:

```
cat(sprintf(
  '%s Re-quantify was set to "True"! Please reanalyse data
  \b with correct settings and start the script again.\n',
  date()))
```

This just deletes the new line in the output.

You could also profit from the fact that `cat` accepts multiple arguments and combines them with a space as separator:

```
cat(sprintf('%s', date()),
  'Re-quantify was set to "True"! Please reanalyse data',
  'with correct settings and start the script again.\n')
```

Comment: No, not really elegant :-) but thanks for this solution. How do other people solve this? Keep longer lines? Or using the paste method?

Comment: What I usually do is put several strings into `cat()`. But this might force you to use several `sprintf()`-calls, which is also not all that nice. I have added this to my solution.

Comment: Hm, still a bit ugly but didn't knew this before... Still wonder if there is no other solution.